# Can union contain objects of a class with user define constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, unions

Can union contain objects of a class with user define constructor? When i try to create a it gives an error saying " member 'c::aa' of union 'c' has user-defined constructor or non-trivial default constructor" 
Is it a standard or is there any mistake in my code?

The code i tested is

```
class a
{  
public:

  int aaa;
  a(){}

};

class b
{

public :

  long bbb;
  b() { }

};

union c
{

public :

  c()  {}

    a aa;
  b bb;  
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to C++11, the answer is "no"--a `union` can only contain value types (to borrow a term from managed code), that is, a type that only contains data members.

`Union`s share their memory footprint across all members.  Having complex members in a union would result in a situation where methods acting on data members of one class would clobber data members of the other class in the union.

Perhaps what you want is a `struct`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used class for the learning purpose. So Is it a bad practice to use class objects or is it an issue which may leads to crash/ambiguous behavior?

Comment: I'd call it a bad practice.  Only use `union` when you explicitly want two objects to share the same memory space.  Nine times out of ten, you should almost always use `struct` and not `union`.

Comment: Under what circumstances is `this` ever stored within the memory of an object?

Comment: It does not matter whether you use class or struct.  A struct can also have a constructor.  Frankly, I'm a bit surprised that a constructor would be an issue since that does not make the memory layout non-trivial.  I thought that C++11 was supposed to relax that rule.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible since C++11 ("unconstrained unions").

Comment: Yet another rich source of eye-watering code. "this will not break any code since it only relaxes an existing rule". As for allowing to write brand new broken software, I bet it will. A gorgeous new playground for the template freaks, no doubt :).

Comment: @kuroi - I don't understand your comment.  Of course it won't break existing code.  Why would it?  What makes you think that writing brand new broken code is allowable?

Comment: I mean that the C++11 guys are a bit too much on the "well, since we can do it, let's just do it" side for my taste. So you can now designate one privilegied member that will be allowed to mess up the contents of all its union siblings. No doubt computer geniuses will make the most of it, but will the benefits outweigh the gazillion bugs caused by mere mortals inadvertently wandering into these virgin lands, I sometimes do wonder. But this is just an idle thought. I don't do C++ for a living anymore.

Comment: No in this case they are just undoing a mistake that should have never been part of the earlier standards, as Bjarn had already pointed out.  There was never any valid reason to prevent classes with trivial functions from being used within unions.  Sorry, but I'm having a little trouble understanding why you think this is bad.  I think it is fantastic.  Why shouldn't I be able to have trivial functions for classes/structs within a union?  It seems useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
class a
{  
public:

  int aaa;
  a(){}

};

class b
{

public :

  long bbb;
  b() { }

};

union c
{

public :

  c()  {}

    a aa;
  b bb;  
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The above code worked fine using the following online compiler.
http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

So the answer is yes and no, depending on your compiler.  MS VS 2010 does not compile that code because it is not yet fully C++11.  Evidently the latest C++11 GCC compiler will compile it just fine!  This is great in my mind, because all along the trivial user defined constructor simply initializes data and it does not change the memory layout.

The C++ 03 standard states that any class or struct with a user defined constructor is non-POD.  Bjarn Stroustrup wrote something about that on his home page indicating that was too strict of a definition for POD vs. non-POD because user defined functions don't always cause a non-trivial memory layout.  That is why the rule was relaxed.